# Добавить класс строке таблицы с определённым содержимым

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, ребята!

Итак, у меня к вам такой вопрос. Как с помощью Javascript найти в таблице слово, и если есть такое слово найдено, то добавить класс, например `highlight`?

Таблица такая:

```
 № | Команда | Игра | Очки
---+---------+------+------
 1 | Бавария | 1    | 3
```

Надо найти в таблице слово «Бавария» и добавить ему класс `highlight`.

Было так:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Бавария</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

И в результате получаем:

```
<tr class="highlight">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Бавария</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Элементарный перебор строк и поиск совпадений: есть совпадение - подсвечиваем!

```js
// Слово для поиска
let word = 'Бавария'.toLowerCase();

// Перебираем все строки
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).forEach(e => 
  // Если в строке есть заданное слово - добавляем класс строке
  e.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(word) ? e.classList.add('highlight') : null
);
```

```css
th{
  text-align: left
}
.highlight{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>№</th>
    <th>Команда</th>
    <th>Игра</th>
    <th>Очки</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Бавария</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Швеция</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Люксембург</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: с одной стороны есть переменная `word// Слово для поиска`, с другой используется `.includes('бавария')`

Comment: @Grundy, старая версия кода, забыл поправить, хотя и так ясно.